# Is it possible to use SurfaceBook as a monitor?

Tags: laptop, display, external-display, microsoft-surface

I got a desktop computer and a SurfaceBook(with performance base), but don't have an extra monitor(even if I have, it'll be difficult for me to find a place to place it...), so I want to use the SB as a monitor when using the desktop.

If you want to know, SB has 1 mini-DP and 2 USB 3.0 (Sorry but that's all it has... ). And I've searched on the internet about using laptop as a monitor, most answers are negative, but there's also someone says few laptop has a HDMI IN port which can be used as a display input; and some other says that this could be done by changing the display settings after "Right Connection".

So is it possible to use a laptop, in my case, Surfacebook, as a monitor?

Comment: No, not in the true sense anyway. If you don't care about graphics performance you could use something like remote desktop / VNC / SplashTop to at least make some use of the desktop